# How to install "libmozjs185-dev" in bionic?

Tags: ubuntu

I want to install `libmozjs185-dev` in ubuntu 18.04, but I can not find commands for do it? Is there `libmozjs185-dev` for bionic?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`libmozjs185-dev` has been removed from the Ubuntu repositories, but you can still download the Debian package from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+package/libmozjs185-dev. Note that `libmozjs185-dev` depends on `libmozjs185-1.0`, which can be downloaded from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+package/libmozjs185-1.0.

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/309343863/libmozjs185-1.0_1.8.5-1.0.0+dfsg-7_amd64.deb
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/309343864/libmozjs185-dev_1.8.5-1.0.0+dfsg-7_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libmozjs185-1.0_1.8.5-1.0.0+dfsg-7_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libmozjs185-dev_1.8.5-1.0.0+dfsg-7_amd64.deb
```

**Update** Oct 2019

I tried this and it failed due to unmet dependencies in the latest ubuntu. I tried it like this instead:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/309343863/libmozjs185-1.0_1.8.5-1.0.0+dfsg-7_amd64.deb
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/309343864/libmozjs185-dev_1.8.5-1.0.0+dfsg-7_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg --force-depends -i libmozjs185-1.0_1.8.5-1.0.0+dfsg-7_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg --force-depends -i libmozjs185-dev_1.8.5-1.0.0+dfsg-7_amd64.deb
```

followed by

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

And that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu Jammie, another dependency is missing besides for those listed in @Notgnoshi's answer:

Use this code:

```
curl -LO http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libf/libffi/libffi6_3.2.1-8_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libffi6_3.2.1-8_amd64.deb
```

to get that dependency first.